# Intellij integrate Gradle and NPM Module

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, npm, auto-import

I am currently working on a project with a React frontend using Node and a Kotlin Spring Boot backend using Gradle. I want to use IntelliJ to edit those projects in the same window. So I opened the root folder as a project and added both the server and the client as modules. My file structure is roughly as follows.

```
/project
- /.idea
- /package.json
- /client
    - /package.json
    - /...
- /server
    - /build.gradle.kts
    - src
```

But if I import it like this my gradle module won't compile without errors and if I click "auto-import changes" in Intellij, it removes my npm module.

How would I go about something like this without making my client a gradle-project (which I definitely do not want!)?